# rtk8192ee wifi firmare stops loading after ifenslave setup attempt (Debian 10)

Tags: debian, wifi, nic, bonding, realtek

I tried setting up Mode 0 NIC bonding using ifenslave between my Ethernet and WiFi cards on Debian 10.

After numerous `ifconfig wls1 up/down`, I was able to set up `Bond0` until it stopped working. After undoing the setup, I realized `ifconfig wls1 up` wasn't loading the WiFi adapter's firmware anymore (rtk8192ee)

> :~$ sudo dmesg | grep firmware
>
> [5.201360] rtl8192ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw.bin
>
> [5.201745] rtl8192ee 0000:24:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw.bin (-2)
>
> [5.201799] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
>
> [5.201845] rtl8192ee 0000:24:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw.bin failed with error -2

I know I'm not missing the firmware because it was working before. Could this be a NetworkManager bug?

Please see my `/etc/network/interfaces`file below

> source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
>
> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback

Any ideas why the firmware is acting up?

Comment: You're missing the firmware. Put it back.

Comment: Lol, how does firmware randomly disappear? Is this a thing?

Comment: It disappears when someone or something removes it. Why that happened to you is not something I can say. But it's plainly not there anymore. So reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks! I put it back by installing "firmware-realtek" package, don't get the firmware error anymore but wls1 still refuses to list on ifconfig.

rtl8192ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw.bin
rtl8192ee 0000:24:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw.bin